# Azure Function loading the wrong assembly?

Tags: azure, npm, azure-functions, azure-bot-service

I'm creating a bot in the Azure Bot Service. I've got a local instance which uses the Azure Functions CLI. I've made an assembly which uses the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` NuGet package. The DLL is placed in the bin folder of the Function. When I run, it below exception comes up.

This seems to be caused by the DLL being loaded from `C:/Users/jaspe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.DLL`. The DLL is there, but it's the wrong version (which is also what the error points out). The question is: why is it loading that one, and not the one I specified in the project.json file. This is the contents of that file:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.8",
        "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure": "3.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Bot.Builder": "3.3.3",
        "mStack.API.Common": "1.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I get from the error is this:

`Appbase = file:///C:/Users/jaspe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin`

Not sure whether that's correct or not. Can / should it load the other version of the packaged dll?

Full error details:

```
Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at obscured.API.Bots.AzureAD.AzureAuthDialog.<LogIn>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at obscured.API.Bots.AzureAD.AzureAuthDialog.<MessageReceivedAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\n (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/jaspe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\\Users\\jaspe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-cli\\bin\\func.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/jaspe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
`
    Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at obscured.API.Bots.AzureAD.AzureAuthDialog.<LogIn>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at obscured.API.Bots.AzureAD.AzureAuthDialog.<MessageReceivedAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IDialogStack-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__21`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUserTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35\n (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/jaspe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\\Users\\jaspe\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-cli\\bin\\func.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.13.8.999, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/jaspe/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/azure-functions-cli/bin/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

**Update**
As mentioned in the comment, here's the contents of project.json.lock specific to this assembly. This seems to be pointing to the correct version.

```json
      "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/3.13.8": {
        "type": "package",
        "compile": {
          "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll": {},
          "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll": {},
          "lib/net45/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll": {}
        }
      },
```

Comment: What version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory was your custom assembly written against? The dll loading from that npm directory is fine, guessing that you're writing and debugging on your local machine.

Comment: Do you see a project.lock.json in your function's folder?

Comment: I do, yes. Do you want me to paste the contents?

Comment: have the same problem, works on a Windows Forms Application, but when running exact the some code on a WPF application, the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing seems to be a bit buggy still. I've managed to fix most of the issues simply by restarting VS. Running under admin credentials also appears to be beneficial although I haven't been able to pinpoint that as begin the real issue.

Comment: Glad to hear this is working for you. The CLI and VS tooling are still in preview and you may indeed hit some rough edges from time to time. If you wouldn't mind opening and describing the issue (and workaround) on the repo (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues) so we can smooth those out, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Of course! I've got some more to spam the repo so sit tight... :) Thanks for all of the good work Fabio, loving it!